# Rails routing issue, No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/test_api"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm reading the book *Rails 4 way* and playing with the routes. The following is my environment information:

```
C:\rails_projects\blog>rake about
About your application's environment
Ruby version              1.9.3-p374 (i386-mingw32)
RubyGems version          1.8.29
Rack version              1.5
Rails version             4.1.6
JavaScript Runtime        Node.js (V8)
Active Record version     4.1.6
Action Pack version       4.1.6
Action View version       4.1.6
Action Mailer version     4.1.6
Active Support version    4.1.6
Middleware                Rack::Sendfile, ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Lock, #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x40279b0>, Rack::Runtime, Rack::MethodOverride, ActionDispatch::RequestId, Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions, ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, ActionDispatch::Reloader, ActionDispatch::Callbacks, ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending, ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement, ActiveRecord::QueryCache, ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, ActionDispatch::Flash, ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, Rack::Head, Rack::ConditionalGet, Rack::ETag
Application root          C:/rails_projects/blog
Environment               development
Database adapter          sqlite3
Database schema version   20140925163909

C:\rails_projects\blog>
```

My routes.rb file is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  root "posts#index"
  
  match "api/v1/:api" => redirect(status: 302) {|params| "/api/" + params[:api] + "_v2"}, via: :any
end
```

My issue is with the `match` line in routes.rb. From my understanding, if I access `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/test_api`, the routing rule should take me to `http://localhost:3000/api/test_api_v2`. However when I access `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/test_api`, I got below error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/test_api"

Rails.root: C:/rails_projects/blog
```

Where is my problem? Is there anything wrong with my understanding regarding routing rule?

---

## Edit, add the output from `rake routes`

```
C:\rails_projects\blog>rake routes
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
    posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
          POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
     root GET    /                         posts#index
          ANY    /api/v1/:api(.:format)    redirect(302)

C:\rails_projects\blog>
```

Comment: run `bundle exec rake routes` and see what routes avaliable.

Comment: Зелёный, I've added the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a `/` at the beginning of your match: `match "/api/v1/:api"...`. And are you sure `:any` is a valid option? The [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints) only mentions `:all`.

Comment: Oh thank you dchop1! Yes the issue is the ":any" part and not the "/" character. When I changed to `:all`, it just works. I use `:any` because it an example from the book I mentioned. Thanks again!